# managed cluster is getting down after sometime in oke

Tags: kubernetes, oracle-cloud-infrastructure

cluster is getting NOT READY state in managed cluster.In oracle cloud it shows warning to add policy

i am trying to add policy
define tenancy ske as ocid1.tenancy.oc1.......
define compartment ske_compartment as ocid1.compartment.....
endorse any-user to associate compute-container-instances in compartment ske_compartment of tenancy ske with subnets
in tenancy where ALL {request}
endorse any-user to associate compute-container-instances in compartment ske_compartment of tenancy ske with vnics in
tenancy where ALL {request}
endorse any-user to associate compute-container-instances in compartment ske_compartment of tenancy ske with
network-security-group in tenancy where ALL {request}